# Omit the code: mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity?

Tags: android

I know it's sort of casting, but i need explanation on why is it necessary? I'm trying to fully understand the line of code. In other words what happens if i omit the line above from the code below:

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, Ipsum.Headlines));
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment) != null) {
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);


    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);


    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

}

Comment: what happens is you don't have a callback, which means notifying that an article was selected is not going to be possible. Anyway, why didn't you just removed it and tested what would happen? The resulting stacktrace would have been plenty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to keep a reference to the container that the fragment is inside. It's just a way to send methods/data back up to the activity. If you don't use that, you can't do things with the container. For example, what if you want to change the fragment that is currently showing from something you carry inside a fragment, e.g press a button or click a list item?

So basically, public methods that you have in your activity will show up when you do mCallback.methodName(); the mCallback is called a 'delegate'. it does actions on behalf of another class.

If you want to read more: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077357/learn-java/delegates.html

Comment: why should i cast activity to an interface to use the interface's methods? i can simply implement it in my main.java.

Comment: implement what in your main.java? doing implements fragmentName then using them methods will do nothing, it has no reference to the applications context